# adding a page to jqtouch

Tags: jqtouch

So I have something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="jqt">
      <div id="page1">
         ...
      </div>
       ....
      <div id="generic">
        Some generic page to use as a template
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I want to create a new page on after everything is loaded and the user does some action.

```
$('#generic').clone().attr('id', 'some_new_page').appendTo('#jqt');
```

What happens is the new page ends up showing up in front of everything and doesn't seem to have and jqtouch events or styles added.

How do initialize this page (or at least have jqtouch reinitialize the whole html file)?

I don't want it to show up at first, I just wanted loaded and ready in the background.

Comment: AFAIK, jQTouch doesn't do much "magic" to the pages. Could you post some example code in jsbin.com?

Comment: What version of jQTouch are you using?

Comment: It is revision 166, which appears to be the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a deep clone with data and events instead?

```
$('#generic').clone(true, true).attr('id', 'some_new_page').appendTo('#jqt');
```